# What should be done if a SPAM post appears under Close Votes Review?

Tags: support

I found a SPAM post under Close Votes review saying 'This question has been flagged as: unclear what you're asking'.

When I was going to close the post as SPAM, I didn't find an option for that.

Do I need to *skip* the review? or voting to close the post as '*unclear what you're asking*' is fine?

I know this is a rare case. But what should be done if it happens again?

Here is the screenshot for that

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you review a post, you have a *link* link that takes you to the post; there you can flag the post as spam.

> [image: screenshot]

I would not vote to vote to close the question, since it is going to be deleted. As you are going to flag it as spam, other users will see it the review queue.

Comment: In addition, the flag as "unclear" is invalid, and a mod should really dismiss is a such.  Only use the spam flag for spam, and only flag spam with the spam flag.